# Azure Python SDK for Blobs - ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient'

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I'm writing code to download a Blob from Azure but I can't import `BlobClient`.

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

cs = "CONNECTION_STRING"

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(cs, container="mycontainer", blob="config.ini")

with open("./config.ini", "wb") as my_blob:
    blob_data = blob.download_blob()
    my_blob.writelines(blob_data.content_as_bytes())
```

I keep getting the error that follows:

```java
$ python3 download.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient'
```

I'm using Virtual Env:

```sh
pip3 install pylint
python3 -m venv env
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

My `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
Flask
azure-storage-blob
```

My Python version is:

```sh
$python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using stable version whereas the `BlobClient` only exists in pre-release.

This solved my problem:

```sh
pip3 install azure-storage-blob --pre
```